# Как показать дочерний элемент при условии, что большая часть его родительского элемента видна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Имеется следующая конструкция:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><div class="hidden">Один</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="hidden">Два</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="hidden">Три</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="hidden">Четыре</div></div>
</div>
```

Как показать дочерний элемент `.hidden` при условии, что большая часть его родительского элемента `.item` видна? Именно по ширине, высота не имеет значения. В противном случае прятать. Благодарю!

Comment: То есть изменение (показать - спрятать `.hidden`) должны происходить при скролле вправо-влево, или з зависимости от размера окна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Собрать массив = координаты между левыми отступами каждой пары дочерних элеметов;
2. При скролле сравнивать `scrollLeft` с полученными координатами;
3. Как только scrollLeft оказался больше одной из координат: Значит элемент с его индексом нужно показывать.

```js
onscroll_toggleItems();

function onscroll_toggleItems() {
  let visible_index = null;
  let points = getSwitchPoints();
  /* Ключевые точки получаются только один раз.
     Предполагается, что ничего не будет динамически менятся.
     Иначе: можно вызывать функцию при каждом скролле */

  let cont = document.querySelector(".container");
  cont.addEventListener("scroll", function() {  
    let new_index;
    for( let i = points.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
      if( this.scrollLeft >= points[i] ) {
        new_index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  
    if( new_index !== visible_index ) {
      /* Не вызывает функцию каждый раз, а только если правда нужно что-то менять. */
      showOnly(new_index);
      visible_index = new_index;
    }
  });
  
  /***/

  function showOnly(index) {  
    let items = document.querySelectorAll(".container .item");
    items.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.children[0].classList[ i === index ? "remove" : "add" ]('hidden');
    });
  }

  function getSwitchPoints() {
    /***
      Берет левый отступ {число} каждого дочернего элемента;
      Для каждой пары элементов считает среднее между этими числами;
      Возвращает массив [0, среднее(0, 1), ..., среднее(N-1, N)];
      Первый - 0, потому что он изначально виден целиком.
    ***/
    
    let parent = document.querySelector(".container");
    let children = document.querySelectorAll(".container .item");

    let parent_left = parent.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let result = [0];

    for( let i = 1; i < children.length; i++ ) {
      let prev = children[i-1].getBoundingClientRect().left - parent_left;
      let curr = children[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().left - parent_left;
      
      result.push( (prev + curr) / 2 );
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><div class="orange hidden">Один</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="orange hidden">Два</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="orange hidden">Три</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="orange hidden">Четыре</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё варианты

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

const toggleClass = entry => {
  if (entry.isIntersecting)
    entry.target.firstElementChild.style.display = 'block'
  else
    entry.target.firstElementChild.style.display = 'none'
}

const callback = entries => entries.forEach(toggleClass)
const options = { threshold: 0.5 }
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
elements.forEach(element => observer.observe(element))
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Один</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Два</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Три</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Четыре</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
let item_size, gap

function init() {
  item_size = items[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
  gap = innerWidth * 0.1
}

function onScroll() {
  const n = Math.floor(container.scrollLeft / (item_size + gap) + 0.5)
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.firstElementChild.style.display = 'none'
    if (i === n) item.firstElementChild.style.display = 'block'
  })
}

container.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
window.addEventListener('resize', init)

init()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Один</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Два</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Три</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hidden">Четыре</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А во втором варианте... откуда берутся магические `* 0.1` и `+ 0.5` ?)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME 0.1 - 10vw, а 0.5 - половина элемента

Comment: я брал его маргины

Comment: За observer, (+), а второй вариант сломается, если item-ам дать разную ширину)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ну если бы задача стояла иначе я бы и делал иначе ) В любом случаем чем больше вариантов, тем лучше.